# Creating a distance matrix for line and/or polygon layers?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, distance-matrix

At 2.18.16, the QGIS tool *Distance Matrix* computes pairwise distances between all **points**, either within one layer or between two layers.  Here's a screenshot for a single layer.  Note that only points (highlighted) are allowed:

[image]

I'm looking for a tool or plugin that extends that *Distance Matrix* concept to include **lines** and **polygons**.  For example, suppose you had a single polygon layer depicting lakes and you wanted to know the distance between each lake and *every other* lake in that same layer (shoreline to shoreline).  Similarly, consider a situation with *two* layers, one of them point and the other polygon, wherein you needed to know the pairwise distances between every point and every polygon outline.

I considered the NNJoin tool, because it accepts points, lines and polygons.  Unfortunately it does not meet my need because it computes only the *single* shortest distance for each feature, whereas I'm interested in *all* distances.

A review of the Processing Toolbox did not turn up anything useful.

I'm considering a workaround that deconstructs lines and/or polygons to their constituent vertices, converts the vertices to points, applies the *Distance Matrix* tool to those points, records the pairwise point distances and then joins those to the original line/point layers.

That workaround seems complex, so before I begin, I'm asking for help: **Is there an easier way to calculate *all* pairwise distances between features - point, line or polygon - either within a layer or between layers?**

Comment: Look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207004/distance-matrix-with-a-linear-feature/207172#207172, that is one way to do it

Comment: @GerardoJimenez, thanks.  The post you linked matched my idea for a workaround.  I'll proceed in that direction.