# Get minimum distance direction from point to line

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, distance, direction

Is there a method using QGis to calculate the **direction (degree)** of the minimum distance from a point to a line.

I already have:
- Point shapefile with hundreds of points;
- Linear Shapefile with coast line;

I'm finding:
- New shapefile with **minimum** direction from to coastline with a column in its attribute table showing the degree (from north) to these lines.

[image: Min dist direction]

Comment: May be this can help : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207004/distance-matrix-with-a-linear-feature/207172#207172, you will get the distance to the nearest node of a line

Comment: Thanks, but I'm searching the DIRECTION (degree) of these minimum distance line!!

Comment: But you need the lines, too, yes? If you follow the linked post to generate these lines, calculating the azimuth is simple.

Answer (score 1):

Open **Field Calculator**, add a new field to your minimum distance lines attribute table.

Enter the expression `degrees( azimuth( start_point( $geometry), end_point( $geometry)))`.