# MMQGIS Distance to nearest hub tool error when using meters

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

When I am using the MMQGIS distance to nearest hub tool with the measurements in meters I am getting the same measurement for all features. This does not happen when using the other units. For ease I would really like to be able to sort this problem.

Please see image below:
[image]

The HubDist column states 3706...etc for all features. My CRS is set to BNG 27700.

Comment: may be this can help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162120/problem-with-distance-matrix-in-qgis-2-83/162168#162168. The problem may be related in using a multipoint layer instead a point layer as noted. Although the main problem is with the distance matrix, it seem it also affected MMqgis distance to nearest hub tool

Comment: Yes that work around did do the job, but it is rather annoying to have to do every time I need this.