# Points Layer to Distance Matrix QGIS 3.6 - Noosa

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, distance-matrix, multipoint

I'm trying to calculate a sample distance matrix from four points in the BNG CRS: [image]

Using Vector-> Analysis Tools -> Distance Matrix, I get:
**Input point layer is a MultiPoint layer - first convert to single points before using this algorithm**

[image: **Input point layer is a MultiPoint layer - first convert to single points before using this algorithm**]

How can I get a distance matrix from my layer of many points?

Comment: in future please put the **text** of your errors in the question not a picture of the error which is much harder to read

Comment: Yup! Did both since wasn't sure what one would need to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error gives also an answer: convert to single points first.  This can be done with the algorithm 'Multipart to singleparts'.

You can link both algorithms in the graphical modeller: processing > graphical modeller (or ctrl + alt + m)

- define as input 'vector layer' and set as point
- link this with algorithm 'Multipart to singleparts'
- link output of previous with algorithm 'distance matrix' -> define an output

[image: ![enter image description here]

Now it should work in one step and can be reproduced for other layers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the graphical modeler (looks super powerful though), so I tried splitting the points via the same command in the toolbox, but it wont let me: *layers were not correctly generated*

Comment: UPDATE: created the workflow, but can't add it to my toolbox because *shutil.SameFileError: *

Comment: May be this can help. It is not for Qgis 3.x but it works https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162120/problem-with-distance-matrix-in-qgis-2-83

Comment: @Newb: I don't know what this error means.  But can you share your files?  So I can do some tests on it?

Comment: @PieterB, I solved: 'shutil.SameFileError:': QGIS didn't like having the model saved into models path directly. I needed to let it load from another directory. (Basically, QGIS doesn't want to load the model since it was in the models folder, but because it wasn't loaded through QGIS I couldn't access it through the GUI). Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: @PieterB, _Re: **layers were not correctly generated** error_: Here is a sample: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12v4p0H6la7doRmliB6awqVrAJKlDyr_7?usp=sharing

Comment: you better use another algorithm to go from multipoint to point: 'Multipart to singlepart'.  I will edit my answer

Comment: Worked like a charm 