# Near Tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, distance

I am looking for an equivalent to the Near- Tool from ArcMap in QGIS. I have a Polygon Layer with potential areas for a new school and need to calculate the distance (in meters) to a point layer (with already existing schools). This is an easy task done with ArcMap but unfortunately I wasn't successful yet with finding a usable tool in QGIS. I am looking for a tool I can add to my model using the graphical modeler. I can't use a plugin. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Calculating minimum distance between points and polygons in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28038/calculating-minimum-distance-between-points-and-polygons-in-qgis)

Comment: There are quiet a few options like NNJoin Plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/