# Measuring distance from a point layer to a raster layer

Tags: qgis

I would like to calculate the distance (in meters) away camera traps (point layer) are to a water source.

Now the water source data I have been given via an external source from the national park I am collecting the data from however I am unsure on how to determine the distance a camera trap is to the nearest water source.

Is this possible to do between a raster layer and a vector point layer?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Nearest distance from point to pixel in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287793/nearest-distance-from-point-to-pixel-in-qgis)

Comment: You could always polygonize your water sources and then compute the distance between the cameras and the polygons. Or is there any reason you would not be able to use this approach?